# Sources for population density map of Europe

Tags: shapefile, data, density, population, choropleth

I want to make population density map for EU where I can show populations of people aged about 65yrs, where can I get a EU shapefile and population Excel file?

Is there any EU shape file available with country boundaries or will I have to create one myself by collecting each country of EU? I have downloaded NUTS 2013 but its attributes hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

From Eurostat database, you can find:

> Population density by NUTS 3 region (**demo_r_d3dens**)

The data in TSV format can be retrieved from [this link](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/product?code=demo_r_d3dens). For excel, format, use [this tool](https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=demo_r_d3dens&lang=en) to filter the dimension you need and retrieve it as XLS format with the download button. The corresponding NUTS geometries can be downloaded ([here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts)). To make a chloropleth map, you need to perform a join, for example with QGIS. Otherwise, [here](https://bl.ocks.org/jgaffuri/0d6e1b1c6f9e1297829f38b9c37737fe) is an example of how to do that quickly with [Eurostat_map.js](https://github.com/eurostat/eurostat.js/blob/master/docs/README-map.md) tool.

Otherwise, for finer spatial analyses, you can get the total population figures over Europe on a 1km resolution grid from [Eurostat-GISCO website](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/grids), for years 2006 and 2011. For more information on how this was produced, see [GEOSTAT 1 project](https://www.efgs.info/geostat/). For a breakdown by age group with this spatial granularity, you have unfortunatelly to wait for some more years, until [the census 2021 regulation](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-manuals-and-guidelines/-/KS-GQ-18-010) is implemented.